# Using Session on PHP

Tags: php, session, localhost

I'm new to PHP programming, I have code for user Login, and already connected to localhost database.

Here is the **Login.php** code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="doLogin.php" method="POST">
            <p>
                <label>Username : </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="user">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Password : </label>
                <input type="text" id="password" name="pass">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" id="btnLogin" value="Login">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and **doLogin.php**

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"];

    $username = stripcslashes($username);
    $password = stripcslashes($password);

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbtest');

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from user where Username = '$username' and Password = '$password' ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    if ($row['Username'] == $username && $row['Password'] == $password)
    {
        echo "You are Success Login!!! Welcome ".$row['Username'];
        header('Location: Profile.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed to login!";
    }
?>
```

I want to using `session` so if the user not logged in, it will redirect to Login page. Where and how I apply a session into my code, much appreciate it.

Comment: at the top. session_start();

Comment: you could have done a simple google search for this. Also do not directly post data from input into your query. Read more on Santizing inputs in PHP. Also, read more on using prepared statements in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some searching and I implement this code.

I create `session.php` file, here is the code

```
<?php
    function checkSession()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION))
        {
            session_start();
        }
        $username=$_SESSION['Username'];
        if(empty($username))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
?>
```

And I place this code for every page that I protect from unauthorized user on top of the code.

```
<?php
    require_once("session.php");
    if(checkSession())
    {
        header('Location: Login.php');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
?>
        //User Logged in...
<?php
    }
?>
```

Hope this could help others new to PHP programming that had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to call `session_start()` and if you don't include partial pages via an index.php or something similar, you need to call `session_start()` on every page or in every file you want to use the session in. Make sure you call `session_start();` at the top of your file, just after `<?php`

In your doLogin.php you could do something like

```
if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
}
```

And at the start of each page you want to protect, check if the session is set like

```
if (!$_SESSION['login'] === true) {
  die('You need to login');
}
```

Very bare bones answer, but that's the basic idea.

And please consider the comment from @PhpDev

Comment: This code perfectly work to prevent user go to page where it need user logged in first. But when user want to logged in, it keep returning to login page. I added this code to my page where I want to protect `<?php
 if(!$_SESSION['login'] === TRUE)
 {
  header('Location: Login.php');
 }?>`

Answer (score 0):

Use session_start() at the beginning and when the user is authenticated then store the username in a session variable.

```
<?php
    session_start(); //starting the session
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"];

    $username = stripcslashes($username);
    $password = stripcslashes($password);

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbtest');

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from user where Username = '$username' and Password = '$password' ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    if ($row['Username'] == $username && $row['Password'] == $password)
    {
        echo "You are Success Login!!! Welcome ".$row['Username'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //Storing username in global variable
        header('Location: Profile.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed to login!";
    }
?>
```